# Need help on Mysql Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to write a mysql trigger to update a field based on the value of other fields in the same table .

I have a table with 3 fields of check boxes namely  checkbox_1, checkbox_2, checkbox_3 . I have another field which is 4th field  , i need to update "status_status" field based on the value present in the checkbox1/2/3 value . I want to update field status_status as 1 if all the checkbox value are 1 .Below is what am trying to do .

```
delimiter $$
create trigger emp_final_status
after update on tester.status_master
for each row
begin
if checkbox_1 = '1' and checkbox_2= '1' and checkbox_3= '1'
 then
update tester.status_master set status_status=1;
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Use trigger `before update` and then instead of `update ... ` just do `set new.status_status = 1`.  But does this logic really belong in the database?

Answer (score 0):

When refering to the fields of the row being updated, use OLD to refer to the value before the change and NEW to refer to the value after the change:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger emp_final_status
BEFORE update on tester.status_master
for each row
begin
if NEW.checkbox_1 = '1' and NEW.checkbox_2= '1' and NEW.checkbox_3= '1'
 then
   set NEW.status_status=1;
END IF;
END
```

I have also changed the trigger from AFTER to BEFORE. In BEFORE trigger, you can affect the updated values.

And I changed your code inside the condition. There, your original code was:

```
   update tester.status_master set status_status=1;
```

This is an `update` statement without a `where` clause, meaning, you are requesting `set status_status=1` for **all the rows** in your table!

Instead, you only want to make change to the one row being processed at the moment:

```
   set NEW.status_status=1;
```